# Pandas does not read sas7bdat file

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I am trying to read a 714MB sas7bdat file with pandas. I sometimes get 
'The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.'.A few times I was given:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas\io\sas\sas.pyx in pandas.io.sas._sas.rle_decompress()

ValueError: unknown control byte: 16

Exception ignored in: 'pandas.io.sas._sas.Parser.process_byte_array_with_data'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\io\sas\sas.pyx", line 104, in pandas.io.sas._sas.rle_decompress
ValueError: unknown control byte: 16
```

I have read similar but bigger files through pandas.read_sas() before.Any ideas are truly appeciated...

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to use different encoding? As state in https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/sas/sas.pyx#L107 , pd.read_sas() cannot convert  your dataset correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As for the kernel dying, if you are using Jupyter Notebooks, then its probably an issue separate from loading the SAS dataset.

As for the error message trying to load the SAS dataset, try `encoding='latin-1'`.